# C++ adding class to a namespace: why?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm a newbie in c++.
Why, in Eclipse (configured with MinGW) and also in other threads, I noticed is used to add a class to a namespace?

I provide an example to show you my actual doubt:

```
#ifndef MODEL_MANGO_HPP_
#define MODEL_MANGO_HPP_

namespace std {

class Mango {
public:
    Mango();
    virtual ~Mango();
};

} /* namespace std */

#endif /* MODEL_MANGO_HPP_ */
```

**EDIT**: As shown in comments, it's completely forbidden to add classes to namespace **std**. Quoting @owacoder,

> Namespaces are never closed, so you always have the ability to add
>   class definitions to them. However, by the specification the std
>   namespace is to be considered closed.

*To provide you a complete view of the context, here is the default implementation of the Mango.cpp, that Eclipse has done for me:*

```
#include "Mango.hpp"
namespace std {
Mango::Mango() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
Mango::~Mango() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
} /* namespace std */
```

So my question changes into:
*Why it's used "namespace std {...}" and when is a good practice to add classes to a namespace?*

Comment: I can't guess why it is done, but I can tell it's forbidden by the specs.

Comment: Namespaces are never closed, so you always have the ability to add class definitions to them. However, by the specification the `std` namespace is to be considered closed.

Comment: @Roberto "[C++11: 17.6.4.2.1/1]: The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited."

Comment: That would be a bug in eclipse. I have never seen this behaviour though.

Comment: If you know people who do that, tell them it is not allowed by the standard. But perhaps you misunderstood and they added `Mango` to their own namespace (not `std`) and used `std` in another context?

Comment: If you are adding classes with the class wizard make sure the namespace field does not say std.  [Check out this example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-stlcdt/fig11.jpg)

Comment: Thanks you all for the comments and details. I edited the question providing quotes to explain how my question has changed.

Comment: @elab look at NathanOliver's comment: it may explain everything.

Comment: _"it's not the best practise to add classes to namespace std"_ no, it's not just "not the best practice" it is completely forbidden. **Do not do it ever**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to understand the basics of what classes and namespaces are.

classes (along with structs, enums, and enum classes) are used to define user defined types in C++.

You create a class to represent a logical entity and encapsulate details, etc.

namespaces are a way to mark territories of code and qualifying unique names for variables.

if you just write a class in a file, it will be written in the "global namespace" and it is not considered good practice because you are "polluting the namespace".

instead, you should use namespaces to limit the scope where your variable names have meaning. this way, you are not exhausting the pool of sensible class and variable names quickly (how many times have you wanted to write a "Utility" class?)

```
namespace firstNamespace{
int x=2;
}

namespace secondNamespace{
int x=7;
}

int main () 
{
std::cout << firstNamespace::x << '\n';
std::cout << secondNamespace::x << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

in this case, you can see that we can "reuse" the variable name x in different Contexts by qualifying a namespace. inside the namespace blocks, we could have more declarations and definitions. including functions, classes, structs, etc.

take not that namespaces remain open and you can add to them later. 
for example you can have this:

```
namespace firstNamespace{
int x=2;
}

namespace secondNamespace{
int x=7;
}

namespace firstNamespace{
int y=11;
}
```

here, we added firstNamespace::y.

More importantly, you can observe that std is a namespace provided by C++ that contains a lot of useful variables, objects like cout which is of type std::ostream, functions and classeslike std::vector, std::ostream, etc.

so to go back to your question, the reason you want to wrap your class definitions in namespaces is to not pollute the global namespace.

Comment: no problem, this is only a very small explanation about why polluting namespace is bad. you should really read on namespaces and how they work. (including using etc)